# How come this Python method does not have "self"?

Tags: python, oop

```
class MM(dict):
    def __init__(self, indexed, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MM, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) #must do it.
        self['name'] = 'hello, this is a value'
        self.go()

    def go(self, kwargs):
        print kwargs #I want this to print out the kwargs
```

How come this  class creates an error when I try to initalize it?

```
>> m = MM()

TypeError: metaMod_Distance() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: What does "How come this Python method does not have 'self'?" have to do with the actual question you asked?

Comment: where `metaMod_Distance()` comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to do:

```
def go(self, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
```

To take keyword only arguments. So the function call will work.

Also you have to pass something else to your constructor (because of unused argument `indexed`):

```
m = MM(1) #or whatever
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code the following way:

```
class MM(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MM, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) #must do it.
        self['name'] = 'hello, this is a value'
        print kwargs
        # Or since you class is subclass of dict
        print self
```

Then

```
m = MM() #will work
```

But if indexed is property you really need then do not forget to specify value for it while creating class:

```
class MM(dict):
    def __init__(self, indexed, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MM, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) #must do it.
        self['name'] = 'hello, this is a value'
        self.indexed = indexed
        print kwargs
        # Or since you class is subclass of dict
        print self
```

Then:

```
indexed = True #since i don't know it's datatype
m = MM(indexed)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is straightforward. You're short one argument. You need to pass in a value for `indexed`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but

1. `__init__` of MM has `indexed` as a arg, which you need to specify when creating an object.
2. Also go method should send a argument when called from **init**. So, in effect this would not give you any problem.

   ```
   class MM(dict):

       def __init__(self, indexed, *args, **kwargs):
           super(MM, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) #must do it.
           self['name'] = 'hello, this is a value'
           self.go(kwargs)

       def go(self, kwargs):
           print kwargs #I want this to print out the kwargs

    m = MM('goone')
   ```

Comment: I took the liberty of double-indenting your code. But that got me wondering whether there is a way to _end_ the list, so that the code can be flush with the margin. [Turns out, there is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34292/160584). Spread the word!